# Not able to scale up App service plan even after scaling the Worker pool in ASE

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I've created the ASE Environment Manually and planned host an App service with P3 App Service plan.

To move forward I have scaled the worker pool1 to P3.

Then added the App Service (Web App) but in App service plan still I see it's only got P1 (small) in premium tier.

How do I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then added the App Service (Web App) but in App service plan still I see it's only got P1 (small) in premium tier.

I can reproduced the issue on my side. I can find the right pricing tier which showing in worker pool.

[image]

It also shows the right pricing plan when I create a web app plan.

[image]

But it always shows Premium: 1 WP1 for pricing plan for the App Plan in portal.

> How do I overcome this situation?

I suggest you ignore this issue. It won't have any impact on your web app/app plan hosted on ASE. Since web app plan host on a ASE worker pool. It will use the resources in the worker pool. So there is **scale out** menu under app plan, we can add or remove instances number if there are enough VM instances in worker pool. It doesn't contain a **scale up** menu because we can't scale up the app plan independently. It will scale up automatically if the worker pool have scaled up.

[image]

Comment: It is just an Azure portal issue. Azure portal doesn't show the right pricing plan for you. You could post this issue on Azure portal bug report page to track this issue. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/category/129061-bug

Comment: Thanks Amor, Yes i have posted my comments on the feedback link